# Why isn't ngRepeat generating an ordered list as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to generate an ordered list, but the number before each list item is always 1.

Part of the html:

```
<ol ng-repeat="student in student.gpas | filter: studentName | orderBy: 'gpa'">
        <li>{{'Name: ' + student.name + ' GPA: ' + student.gpa}}</li>            
    </ol>
```

Part of the JavaScript:

```
$scope.student = {
    gpas: [
    { name: "a c", gpa: 3.5 },
    { name: "b c", gpa: 2.5 },
    { name: "c c", gpa: 1.5 },
    { name: "d c", gpa: 0.5 }
    ]
};
```

Result:

[image]

Why isn't the ordered list working?

Comment: Inspect the HTML and you would see why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-repeat should be done over **`li`** not **`ol`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.student = {
    gpas: [
    { name: "a c", gpa: 3.5 },
    { name: "b c", gpa: 2.5 },
    { name: "c c", gpa: 1.5 },
    { name: "d c", gpa: 0.5 }
    ]
};
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body ng-controller="Main">
<ol>
   <li ng-repeat="student in student.gpas | filter: studentName | orderBy: 'gpa'"> 
           {{'Name: ' + student.name + ' GPA: ' + student.gpa}}
   </li>            
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ng-repeat` in `ol` use it in `li`

```
<ol>
        <li ng-repeat="student in student.gpas | filter: studentName | orderBy: 'gpa'"> 
           {{'Name: ' + student.name + ' GPA: ' + student.gpa}}
       </li>            
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="student in student.gpas | filter: studentName | orderBy: 'gpa'"> 
       {{'Name: ' + student.name + ' GPA: ' + student.gpa}}
    </li>            
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ng-repeat` inside `<li>` element not in `<ol>` element. Something like this:

```
<ol >
    <li ng-repeat="student in student.gpas | filter: studentName | orderBy: 'gpa'">
     {{'Name: ' + student.name + ' GPA: ' + student.gpa}}</li>            
</ol>
```